# Is there any way to just get rid of the RPG profile without the others?

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm really frustrated, and a bit stuck.  At the end of the day, posting on the RPG stack only ends up in aggravation.  Can anyone tell me how to delete just the RPG profile without effecting the Stack Overflow or any of the other profiles?

Comment: I noticed your profile, care to have a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13848/not-a-bar-but-plays-one-on-tv) about this at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can request account deletion on *just* your RPG.SE profile. Please follow the instructions [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/contact) by selecting account deletion in the dropdown.